# How can I define a Typescript interface for a function?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am defining the following Typescript interface. clickCustomButton1 should return nothing but I am not sure how to specify that.

```
interface IButtonTemplate {
    clickCustomButton1: (); // How can I say this should return nothing?
    // more code here
}
```

I use this in my code like this:

```
clickCustomButton1: null
```

then later:

```
newTopicTests = () => {
}

clickCustomButton1 = this.newTopicTests();
```

It's giving me an error saying:

```
Error   2   Cannot convert 'void' to '() => boolean'
```

Can someone give me an idea what I am doing wrong? What I think I need to do is to specify that clickCustomButton1 and also the newTopicTests do not return anything. But how can I do that with Typescript?

Comment: user2864740 - I am sorry but I am not sure what I understand what you mean. I added a line to my question asking if someone can show me how I can do this and make it work when anything I assign to clickCustomButton1 should meet the criteria that it return nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because the lambda `() => {}` is typed as `(): void` because it returns nothing and thus has no [other] type inferred.

Thus, given `f = () => {}`, the expression `f()` is also typed as `void` - but clickCustomButton1 *must* return a `boolean` as it is declared.

Compare when using the following lambda, which is typed as `(): boolean`, which is now type-valid:

```
newTopicTests = () => true
```

Another way to see this problem is to write the original code as:

```
newTopicTests = (): boolean => {}
```

(This will also fail to compile, but will show the error closer to where it the source.)

---

After the updates to the question..

To declare a *method* in an Interface to return nothing, use:

```
clickCustomButton1(): void;
```

To declare a *member* which has the type of `(): void`, use

```
clickCustomButton1: () => void;
```

Also note that `null` *is* something whereas void represents nothing.